# Network traffic saturation causing failover

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows failover cluster and every time I take a remote robocopy backup from this cluster it seems like it's causing such high network saturation that the cluster monitor thinks the NIC is unresponsive and then fails over.

This is my assumption based on the time of day this usually happens.

I've tried adding the /IPG flag to robocopy to allow some space between packets.  Is there anything else I could consider to space traffic out?  I've had similar problems that aren't robocopy related.  Perhaps a network interface tweak?

Thanks.

Comment: How many NIC's on each cluster host? What services/applications are you clustering? Run the following from PowerShell and post the output here: Get-ClusterNetwork | FT Name, Metric

Comment: I don't seem to have that cmdlet available to me.

Comment: You probably need to import the module: import-module failoverclusters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the network during normal hours when you're not running the Robocopy job. Do you see congestion? Do you see a high volume of broadcast traffic? Are links saturated? Take a look at link speed and duplex settings.

In general, take a look at the network as a whole before you start tweaking server and/or switch settings. The key to knowing when something isn't working normally is to know what it looks like when it is working normally. If the network is performing poorly in it's normal state then the added load of your Robocopy job is only going to exacerbate it.

EDIT

In addition, depending on your configuration you can prevent cluster communication (heartbeat traffic) from transiting the network that you're doing the Robocopy job over. If the 
Robocopy job is running over an iSCSI network then you shouldn't have cluster communication enabled on that network to begin with.

Comment: I have a separate iSCSI switch pair with 4 dedicated interfaces to iSCSI on both servers.  I have a separate physical interface on each with a crossover cable for hear-beat. Then I have a pair of teamed interfaces going to my core switch for job traffic.

I'll keep a lookout for how much traffic the jobs work up, but I didn't think it would be too much.  The jobs run in batch and certain times of the day.  Maybe all I need to do is move schedules around.

Thank you.

Comment: The cluster will use any network adapter for cluster communications as long as the "allow cluster network communication on this network" setting is enabled, which may not be what you want. I think that knowing the metric for each cluster network is going to go a long way in determining why the cluster is failing over during the Robocopy job.

Comment: I see.  Here is the output of my network metrics:
Heartbeat=1000, iSCSI=10000, LAN=1000

Comment: I'm fairly new to failover clustering but here's a link that goes into some detail, especially regarding the network metrics - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2011/06/17/10176338.aspx

Comment: The Heartbeat and LAN networks have the same metric which means that heartbeat traffic will go over both. If the LAN network becomes saturated and the heartbeat isn't responded to on that network that might explain things. AFAIK, it's recommended to have multiple networks for heartbeat traffic but in your case it may make sense to isolate the heartbeat traffic to just the Heartbeat network (which it seems you were intending with the crossover cable). You can do this by disabling the "allow cluster network communication on this network" setting on the LAN network.

Comment: Disabling the "allow cluster network communication on this network" on the LAN network should give it a metric of 10100. You'll be left with only a single network for heartbeat traffic which leaves you with a SPOF for heartbeats. In addition, I'm not sure what failover clustering does in a "split-brain" scenario if the heartbeat network goes down. Each cluster host will think it's still alive and the other is dead, which might lead to unexpected results, depending on how you have your clustered services/applications configured.

Comment: Just FYI, I did what you suggested and placed all cluster traffic only on the heartbeat network and it's not failing over any more.  I still have the robocopy congestion which is causing production jobs to stall.  I've started a new thread around that though.

Thank you for the reply.

Comment: So this fixed the original issue then?